# Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I need some help to ressolve the following crash. I am refreshing my list on Restart in `Activity` by calling `fragment` in `viewpager` to refresh its list. Following is the stacktrace of the crash:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.checkActivity(ViewModelProviders.java:51)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(ViewModelProviders.java:105)
       at com.ui.fragments.mainpagerfragments.ConversationListFragment.searchConversation(ConversationListFragment.java:383)
       at com.ui.activities.HomeActivity.onRestart(HomeActivity.java:288)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
       at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6365)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6376)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3345)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

call from activity onRestart :

```
((MyListFragment) adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(0)).search("");
```

method in fragment :

```
public void search(String query) {

        query = "%" + query + "%";
        if (myListViewModel == null) {
            myListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyListViewModel.class);
        }
        if (myListViewModel.mList != null && myListViewModel.mList.hasActiveObservers()) {
            myListViewModel.mList.removeObservers(this);
        }
        myListViewModel.getFilteredList(query).observe(this, mainObserver);
    }
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Updated with patch of related code as I cant post complete code here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using a viewpager, be sure that the corresponding fragment is actually attached to its activity (this is what the error tries to tell you). It might happen that the fragment is not visible, thus it's not attached (depending on how the view pager was configured).

a quick&dirty fix:

```
public void search(String query) {

    if(!isAdded()) return; //<---- returns if the fragment is not attached

    query = "%" + query + "%";
    if (myListViewModel == null) {
        myListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyListViewModel.class);
    }
    if (myListViewModel.mList != null && myListViewModel.mList.hasActiveObservers()) {
        myListViewModel.mList.removeObservers(this);
    }
    myListViewModel.getFilteredList(query).observe(this, mainObserver);
}
```

However, you should re-investigate in your architecture, because those checks often imply some other code smells. When you're working with the new Android Architecture Patterns, there should be no need of this check as the lifecycle pattern handles all this for you: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

So, basically, you should not directly call any function of a fragment directly, instead call the corresponding business logic, which notifies the fragment to update its views.

Comment: isAttach() method not found... And can I attach fragment if it is detached in the same method ?

Comment: Like if(isDetached()){
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .attach(this)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

Comment: Sorry, my fault: it should be `isAdded()`. You should not try to attach the fragment in place and assume, that the rest of the code will work, because the attach process is asynchronous and the function will probably still fail unless you wait for the attachment. Again, consider some refactoring of your code. Stated here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel you should create your model once when the fragment was created and update the model in the corresponding functions.

Comment: @DenisLoh Can you please demonstrate the way of updating only the business logics from one fragment to another without calling their methods?

Answer (score 8):

Since the error is that the fragment is not attached yet, it needs to be done when we are sure the fragment is actually attached. Its a good way of doing this; by putting the code inside the override method *onAttach*

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    myListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyListViewModel.class);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer - what exactly is the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: @Markus Thought it was pretty obvious why this fixed it, and how I fixed it is the answer. But I can explain more in the answer. Please remove your downvote.