# onDetach() not calling in moving from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

When i get values back from FragB(A bottomsheetfragment launched from the toolbar of the ativity) to FragA(from viewpager of activity) and call the method of FragA via interface to hit the API's again with the new data it gives me the following exception:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create ViewModelProvider for detached fragment**

Here after getting the data from FragB to activity i am calling method of FragA from activity by using:

```
val getFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)

        if(getFragment is GrowthStoryFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
```

So after reading from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246796/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cant-create-viewmodelprovider-for-de) SO thread it says go for a null check or re-initialize the viewModel in onAttach but the strange behavior here is that no lifecycle method of FragA is being called  when i launch the bottomsheetfragment(FragB) from the toolbar of activity and when i dismiss() the FragB on a button click then only the lifecycle methods of FragB are being called and again no lifecycle method of viewpager fragment FragA are calling so when the fragment got detached and now from where i should re-initialize the viewModel and other instances?

Please help me to understand this scenario.

**Update**:
Here's the Activity code:

```
class ViewDetailsActivity : BaseActivity(), FilterOptionsDialogFragment.onApplyEventListener, BusinessUnitDialogFragment.afterDoneClick {


    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter
    private var myFragmentFlag = 0

    private var TAG = "ViewDetailsActivity"

    override fun getContentView(): Int = R.layout.activity_view_details

    override fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, intent: Intent?) {


        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Growth Story"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Share Story"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Purchase Dynamics"))
        tabLayout!!.addTab(tabLayout!!.newTab().setText("Brand Health Track"))
        tabLayout.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
        tabLayout.tabGravity = Gravity.CENTER
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#a1a1a1"), Color.parseColor("#ff8a00"))

        pagerAdapter = ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager, tabLayout!!.tabCount)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        viewPager.isFocusableInTouchMode = true

        scrollListener()

        viewPager!!.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

        tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager!!.currentItem = tab.position
                when (tab.position) {
                    0 -> {
                        myFragmentFlag = 0
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.GONE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        myFragmentFlag = 1
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        myFragmentFlag = 2
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        myFragmentFlag = 3
                        left_scroll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        right_scroll.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        })

        tvTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._16ssp))
        tvTitle.setText("Category Deep Dive")
        ivBack.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            finish()
        })
        ivLogo.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val addFrag = FilterOptionsDialogFragment.newInstance()
            addFrag.show(supportFragmentManager, "add")
        })

        vd_edit_icon.setOnClickListener({
            val buFrag = BusinessUnitDialogFragment.newInstance()
            buFrag.show(supportFragmentManager, "add")
        })

        vd_edit_icon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun scrollListener() {
        left_scroll.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val itemnum = viewPager.currentItem
            viewPager.currentItem = itemnum - 1
        })

        right_scroll.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val itemnum = viewPager.currentItem
            viewPager.currentItem = itemnum + 1
        })
    }

    override fun someEvent(countryId: String?, dateRange: String?, specs: String?) {
        val getFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)

        if(getFragment is GrowthStoryFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is ShareStoryFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is PurchaseDynamicsFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }else if(getFragment is BrandHealthFragment){
            getFragment.myfilterOptions(countryId, dateRange, specs)
        }
    }

    override fun onDoneClicked(item: String) {

        val getFragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)

        if(getFragment is GrowthStoryFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is ShareStoryFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is PurchaseDynamicsFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }else if(getFragment is BrandHealthFragment){
            getFragment.getBuName(item)
        }

    }

}
```

**Fragment Adapter:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter

class ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager,internal var totalTabs: Int): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 ->  return GrowthStoryFragment()
            1 -> return ShareStoryFragment()
            2 -> return PurchaseDynamicsFragment()
            3 -> return BrandHealthFragment()
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    // this counts total number of tabs
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return totalTabs
    }

}
```

**Fragment A:**

```
class GrowthStoryFragment : Fragment() {

    private val TAG = "GrowthStoryFragment"
    private  lateinit var disposable : Disposable
    private lateinit var responseSpinner : List<RespCat>
    private lateinit var responseFirstBarChart : List<RespBrand>
    private lateinit var RespDon : List<RespDon>
    private lateinit var responseSecondBarChart : List<RespDist>

    companion object{

        private lateinit var myApplicationContext : Context
        private var countryID = "1"
        private var date = "MAT TY"
        private var spec  = "val"

        private var businessUnitID = "2"
        private var category = "Fresh Milk"
        private var firstReportTypeId = "1"       //fixed for growth story and share story
        private var isGroup = "false"             //fixed to false
    }

    private lateinit var userModel : UserViewModel

    private val backendApi = WinRetrofitHelper.winApiInstance()

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnAttach")
        userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        Log.e(TAG, "OnCreateView")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_growth_story, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnViewCreated")
        myApplicationContext = context!!.applicationContext
        getSpinnerResponse(businessUnitID, isGroup,firstReportTypeId)
//        getSuperRegionName(countryID, date,spec," ",businessUnitID, category, firstReportTypeId, isGroup)

        growth_spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val item  = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as RespCat
                category = item.nameValue
                Log.e(TAG,"Category name is: " + category)
                getSuperRegionName(countryID, date,spec," ",businessUnitID, category, firstReportTypeId, isGroup)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun getSpinnerResponse(businessUnitID: String, isGroup: String, firstReportTypeId: String){

        userModel.getResponseGrowthSpinner(businessUnitID, isGroup, firstReportTypeId)
        userModel.responseGrowthSpinner.observe(this,
                Observer {
                    Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                    growth_spinner.adapter = GrowthSpinnerAdapter(it)
                })
    }

    private fun getSuperRegionName(countryID: String, date: String, spec: String, superMarket: String,businessUnitID: String, category: String, firstReportTypeId: String, isGroup: String) {

        userModel.getResponseSuperRegion(countryID)
        userModel.responseSuperRegion.observe(this,
                Observer {
                    Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                    getDataFromApi(countryID, date, spec, it!!.get(0).nameValue, businessUnitID, category, firstReportTypeId, isGroup)
                })
    }

    private fun getColorID(position: Int): Int {
        try {
            val rnd = Random
            when (position) {
                0 -> return R.color.brand_almarai
                1 -> return R.color.brand_alsafi
                2 -> return R.color.brand_nadec
                3 -> return R.color.brand_sadafco
                4 -> return R.color.brand_nestle
                5 -> return R.color.brand_amul
                6 -> return R.color.brand_nada
            }
            return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
        }catch (e :Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return 1
    }

     fun myfilterOptions(countryId: String?, dateRange: String?, specs: String?){
         userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]
         getSuperRegionName(countryId!!,dateRange!!,specs!!.toLowerCase()," ",businessUnitID, category, firstReportTypeId, isGroup)
        Log.e(TAG, "Growth Story Fragment:" +countryId!!+" "+dateRange!!+" "+specs!!.toLowerCase()+ " "+businessUnitID+ " "+category+ " "+firstReportTypeId+ " "+isGroup)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.e(TAG, "Ondestroy")
        disposable.dispose()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnCreate")
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnActivitycreated")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnPause")
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnStart")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnResume")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnStop")
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Log.e(TAG, "Ondestroyview")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnDetach")
    }

}
```

**FragB** code:

```
class FilterOptionsDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private var myResp: List<RespBu>? = null
    private lateinit var myView: View
    private lateinit var customList: ArrayList<RespBu>
    private var dateRange: String = ""
    private var specrange: String = ""
    private lateinit var onmyApplyEventListener: onApplyEventListener
    private var TAG = "FilterOptionsDialogFragment"

    val pref: AppPreference by lazy {
        AppPreference.getInstance(context!!)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): FilterOptionsDialogFragment {
            return FilterOptionsDialogFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
                              @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_options_layout, container, false)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnCreateView")
        // get the views and attach the listener

        val backendApi = WinRetrofitHelper.winApiInstance()
        val request = backendApi.getBUCountry()

        request.enqueue(object : Callback<List<RespBu>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<RespBu>>?, t: Throwable?) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<RespBu>>?, response: Response<List<RespBu>>?) {
                val spinner = myView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.filter_options_spinner)

                spinner.adapter = Spinner_filter_options(getNewList(response?.body()))
                if(pref.getString("BuID") != null && !pref.getString("BuID").equals("")){

                    if(pref.getBoolean(Site.BUSINESS_UNIT_FRONT)!=null && pref.getBoolean(Site.BUSINESS_UNIT_FRONT))
                        filter_options_spinner.setSelection(pref.getString("BuID").toInt()-1)
                    else
                        filter_options_spinner.setSelection(pref.getString("BuID").toInt()-1)
                }
            }
        })

        return myView
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnStart")
    }

    private fun getNewList(mylist: List<RespBu>?): List<RespBu> {
        if(pref.getBoolean(Site.BUSINESS_UNIT_FRONT)!=null && pref.getBoolean(Site.BUSINESS_UNIT_FRONT))
            return mylist!!
        else{
            customList = ArrayList()
            customList.add(RespBu("0", 0, "Global", 0))
            for (item in mylist.orEmpty()) {
                customList.add(item)
            }
            return customList
        }

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        try {

            if (pref.getString("dateName") != null && !pref.getString("dateName").equals("")) {
                if (pref.getString("dateName").equals("YTD"))
                    date_ytd.isChecked = true
                else
                    date_mat.isChecked = true
            }

            if (pref.getString("specName") != null && !pref.getString("specName").equals("")) {
                if (pref.getString("specName").equals("VAL"))
                    spec_val.isChecked = true
                else
                    spec_vol.isChecked = true
            }

            val dateradiogroup = view.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.date_radio_group)
            val specradiogroup = view.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.spec_radio_group)

            view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.view_close).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            })

            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.apply).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                val dateRadioBtn = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(dateradiogroup.checkedRadioButtonId)
                val specRadioBtn = view.findViewById<RadioButton>(specradiogroup.checkedRadioButtonId)
                val respBu = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.filter_options_spinner).selectedItem as RespBu

                val buName = respBu.keyValue.toString()
                val dateName = dateRadioBtn.text.toString()
                val specName = specRadioBtn.text.toString()

                pref.saveString("BuID", filter_options_spinner.selectedItemId.toString())
                pref.saveString("dateName", dateName)
                pref.saveString("specName", specName)
                pref.saveString("BuName", respBu.keyValue.toString())

                onmyApplyEventListener.someEvent(buName, dateName + " TY", specName)
                Log.e("Filter item", respBu.nameValue + " " + dateRadioBtn.text)
                dismiss()
            })


            view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.filter_options_spinner).onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    }

    interface onApplyEventListener {
        fun someEvent(countryId: String?, dateRange: String?, specs: String?)
    }

    override fun onAttach(activity: Activity?) {
        super.onAttach(activity)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnAttach")
        onmyApplyEventListener = activity as onApplyEventListener
    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate")
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        Log.e(TAG, "OnActivitycreated")
    }

//    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
//        super.onAttach(context)
//        onmyApplyEventListener = context as onApplyEventListener
//        Log.e(TAG, "OnAttach")
//    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnPause")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnResume")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnStop")
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Log.e(TAG, "Ondestroyview")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.e(TAG, "Ondestroy")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        Log.e(TAG, "OnDetach")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I really think I have it this time:

`ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter#getItem` is returning a fresh instance every 
time. When you later call `#getItem`, you're getting an un-initialized fragment instance that is also not currently attached to any `Activity`. As a result, nothing you do will get what you're looking for. By making sure you hand back the exact same instance each time for a given page type, you should be safe.

You have mentioned that `FragmentManager#getFragments` returns a list that has the fragment you had initialized earlier. You can use this to your advantage by getting the fragment you want by type from the fragments that the given `FragmentManager` knows about:

```
class ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager,internal var totalTabs: Int): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return when (position) {
            0 ->  existing<GrowthStoryFragment>() ?: GrowthStoryFragment()
            1 -> existing<ShareStoryFragment>() ?: ShareStoryFragment()
            2 -> existing<PurchaseDynamicsFragment>() ?: PurchaseDynamicsFragment()
            3 -> existing<BrandHealthFragment>() ?: BrandHealthFragment()
            else -> return null
        }
        }

    private inline fun <reified T> existing(): T? =
        supportFragmentManager.getFragments().firstOrNull { it is T } as T?
```

[SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray) is just a `Map<Int, ?>` that's suggested by Android. You can instead track the list of fragments you've handed out inside your adapter instance in one. The upside here is that it's theoretically more performant, and you're keeping knowledge local. The theoretical downside is that you're holding onto framework-managed objects with a potentially different scope than the framework uses.

```
class ViewDetailsFragmentAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager,internal var totalTabs: Int): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {
    private val pages: SparseArray<Fragment> by lazy(:: { SparseArray(totalTabs) }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        return pages.get(position) ?:
            when (position) {
                0 -> GrowthStoryFragment()
                1 -> ShareStoryFragment()
                2 -> PurchaseDynamicsFragment()
                3 -> BrandHealthFragment()
                else -> null
            }.also { pages.put(position, it) }
        }
```

Comment: as OnAttach was not calling again so i did this here too

Comment: could always see what using `requireActivity` as esr's answer suggests:

Comment: private val userModel: UserViewModel get() = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())[UserViewModel::class.java]

Comment: When swiping to other app this code is giving me the error of: Fragment is already added.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels should be initiated for application context. Like this:
someViewModel = activity.let { ViewModelProvider(**requireActivity()**).get(SomeViewModel::class.java) }

Although you did not paste proper part of code - I suspect you are tying ViewModel lifecycle to fragment - which you get by requireContext() inside fragment.

Try with requireActivity()

update since code is provided: 
 userModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

this - is reference to Fragment. What I wrote by blind guessing is correct. Use requireActivity()